# Primefaces gmap view is not rendered after returned /called by a backing bean

Tags: java, primefaces, jsf-2

In a method of a backing bean the Mapmodel, markers and other
   information is prepared to show a collection of club  members in a 
   selected distance like 60 kilometers. After everything is done the JSF
   page "display_all_in_distance.xhtml" is returned. Unfortunately  the 
   map and  markers are not rendered.However when I run the xhtml file 
   separately the page is shown like is 
   should be. How can I achieve to run this as wanted.  See code below.

```
 public String displayMembersInDesiredDistance() {
    // define Map Model       
    //  GeoApiContext context = new GeoApiContext();
    modelMap = new DefaultMapModel();
    //set Mapcenter und Circle für address of member doing the search
    mapCenter = determineMapCenter(getHomeLatitude(), getHomeLongitude());
    Circle circle = new Circle(new LatLng(getHomeLatitude(), t(i).getKdLng());
    StringBuilder infoMarker = new StringBuilder();
    infoMarker.append(getListeDistanceKontaktdaten().get(i).getKdFamilienname()).append(", ").append(getListeDistanceKontaktdaten().get(i).getKdOrt()).append(", ").append(getListeDistanceKontaktdaten().get(i).getKdStrasse()).append(", ").append(getListeDistanceKontaktdaten().get(i).getKdHausnummer());
    modelMap.addOverlay(new Marker(coordinate, infoMarker.toString()));

    return "display_all_in_distance.xhtml";
}
```

XHTML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <f:view contentType="text/html">
        <f:loadBundle var="msg" basename="messages" />  
    </f:view> 
    <!--  Definitions head -->
    <h:head>
        <script  src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBvT-XXY97dvqmlet7nvWP1lIXSfaPvz9U" type="text/javascript">
        </script>
        <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv="Content-Type"/>                
        <title> value="#{msg['AbcOnlineApplications']}"
        </title> 
    </h:head> 
    <!--  Definitions body -->   
    <h:body>
        <f:view contentType="text/html">
            <h:form styleClass="form-horizontal" id="displaymapForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" prependId="false" acceptcharset="UTF-8">  
                <p:messages id="message" severity="info,warn,error" globalOnly="true" autoUpdate="true"/>
                <p:layout fullPage="true">
                    <p:layoutUnit position="center">   
                        <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px;margin-left:10px" cellpadding="10" >
                            <img src="resources/img/029.jpg" width="200"  height="100" />
                            <img src="resources/img/ABC_logo.png" width="250"  height="100" style="margin-left:100px"  />
                        </h:panelGrid>

                        <p:gmap center="#{showMembersInDistanceTo.mapCenter}" zoom="10" type="HYBRID"  id="gmap"
                                style="width:100%;height:600px" streetView="true"
                                model="#{showMembersInDistanceTo.modelMap}">
                            <p:ajax event="overlaySelect" listener="#{showMembersInDistanceTo.onMarkerSelect}"/> 
                            <p:gmapInfoWindow>
                                <h:outputText value="#{showMembersInDistanceTo.marker.data}"/>
                            </p:gmapInfoWindow>
                        </p:gmap>
                        <p:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-default"
                                         style="color: green"
                                         action="/enter_familyname.xhtml" value="#{msg['Back']}">
                        </p:commandButton> 
                    </p:layoutUnit>
                </p:layout>
            </h:form>    
        </f:view> 
    </h:body>  
</html>
```

Comment: whey do you want to return display_all_in_distance.xhtml

Comment: Sorry for not answering (was ill).

Comment: I need tp display the google map therefore I return the xhtmö file. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Also I noticed, that sometimes display_all_in_ distance.xhtml DOES render everything, but in most cases it does not work. I beleive that  the IDE (Netbeans) could be the problem.  I will deploy the app directly to glassfish to find this out (had no time yet)